# slash and backslash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, path

I want to write a application that works in windows and linux. but I have a path problem because windows use "\" and Linux use "/" .how can I solve this problem.
thanks

Answer (score 22):

In Ruby, there is no difference between the paths in Linux or Windows. The path should be using `/` regardless of environment. So, for using any path in Windows, replace all `\` with `/`. `File#join` will work for both Windows and Linux. For example, in Windows:

```
Dir.pwd
=> "C/Documents and Settings/Users/prince"

File.open(Dir.pwd + "/Desktop/file.txt", "r")
=> #<File...>

File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd, "Desktop", "file.txt"), "r")
=> #<File...>

File.join(Dir.pwd, "Desktop", "file.txt")
=> "C/Documents and Settings/Users/prince/Desktop/file.txt"
```

Comment: Ohh if this only worked when you want to run external commands.

Comment: ... not true, in windows there are special prefixes like \\?\ (required for paths >260bytes) which get converted to //?/ which have no meaning at all... So the feature is indeed a bug afaict

Comment: @estani I didnt say it is a feature. I said `File.join` and infact all paths are seperated by `/` regardless of the environment. That is how paths are represented in ruby and you have to use `/` even in case of Windows for file paths while initializing a file.

Comment: @rubyprince you are right. Though join uses a separator constant it is hardcoded to be */*... from file.c `separator = rb_obj_freeze(rb_usascii_str_new2("/"));` This is so wrong...

Comment: On windows I had to add the colon to the 'c' path:  ` "C:/Documents and Settings/Users/prince/Desktop/file.txt"`

Comment: I think the above comment by estani may no longer be true; if I recall, ruby uses some dynamic check these days on windows (on linux we don't even need it since linux is superior to windows anyway). But I am not 100% sure so perhaps someone else can confirm it.

Answer (score 13):

As long as Ruby is doing the work, `/` in path names is ok on Windows

Once you have to send a path for some other program to use, especially in a command line or something like a file upload in a browser, you have to convert the slashes to backslashes when running in Windows.

`C:/projects/a_project/some_file.rb'.gsub('/', '\\')` works a charm. (That is supposed to be a double backslash - this editor sees it as an escape even in single quotes.)

Use something like this just before sending the string for the path name out of Ruby's control.

You will have to make sure your program knows what OS it is running in so it can decide when this is needed.  One way is to set a constant at the beginning of the program run, something like this

`::USING_WINDOWS = !!((RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win|w)(32|64)$/) || (RUBY_PLATFORM=~ /mswin|mingw/))`

(I know this works but I didn't write it so I don't understand the double bang...)

Comment: I believe the `!!` converts it to a boolean. In ruby true is usually returned as non-nil or non-false objects (you would get a Match object in your case). `!` converts object to `false` and the second `!` converts it to `true`.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at File.join: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000031

Comment: It seems to "join" method be for linux T How can I use join method for windows ?

Comment: Depending on your plattform `File.join` will either use \ or / as separator.

Comment: Actually `File.join` uses `/` on Windows too.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Pathname` class to generate paths which then will be correct on your system:

```
a_path = Pathname.new("a_path_goes_here")
```

The benefit of this is that it will allow you to chain directories by using the `+` operator:

```
a_path + "another_path" + "and another"
```

Calling `a_path.to_s` will then generate the correct path for the system that you are on.

Comment: Don't forget require "pathname" unless you're running on a ginormous web development framework.

Comment: This doesn't work for Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows unless I'm missing something:
  p = Pathname.new("")
  p = p + "apple" + "banana"
  puts p.to_s   <-- "apple/banana"

Comment: Use File.join instead, it is simpler and less annoying than pathname - and it will work just fine.

Comment: @shevy [citation needed]. Why is it "less annoying"?

Comment: I also think that `File.join` will still use `/` even on Windows machines. `Pathname` will use whatever the OS says.

Comment: Both pathname and File join will use `/`. Ruby under the hood will know what to do with a `/` depending on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's annoying as a windows users to keep replacing those backslashes to slashes and vice-versa if you need the path to copy it to your filemanager, so i do it like his.
It does no harm if you are on Linux or Mac and saves a lot of nuisance in windows.

```
path = 'I:\ebooks\dutch\_verdelen\Komma'.gsub(/\\/,'/')

Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.epub").each do |file|
    puts file
end
```