# Why does rubocop's Rails/FilePath cop recommend Rails.root.join

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following line in my code:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/config/environments/production.rb"
```

Rubocop's `Rails/FilePath` cop recommends I change it to:

```
require Rails.root.join('config', 'environments', 'production.rb')
```

Why?  The former is more compact, appears faster and is arguably more readable.

Comment: `Rails.root.join` actually generates forward slashes on windows or more generalized: `File.join` is not platform specific where a string with slashes is.

Comment: The path separator is platform dependent. AFAIK Windows will accept `/` most of the time but it really wants to see a backslash (which I can't seem to get past Markdown). Presumably `Rails.root.join` will use the correct separator. Not sure about Rubocop and I haven't touched Windows in decades so just a comment.

Comment: This question is out of date, the new default is to use the full path: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails/issues/195

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As other's have mentioned, RuboCop recommends doing this to avoid problems with Operating Systems that don't use `/` as the path separator.  The RuboCop team added some clarification after this question was asked (as seen at https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pull/5571/files).

That being said, I'm not sure this cop is necessary.  From other SO threads, like [slash and backslash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173000/slash-and-backslash-in-ruby), it sounds like Ruby does a good job of automatically converting paths behind the scenes (when code is executing in Ruby).  In the cases where paths are being passed to external systems, people will probably be very specific about the path structure.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Rubocop manual](https://docs.rubocop.org/projects/rails/en/stable/cops_rails/#railsfilepath)

> This cop is used to identify usages of file path joining process to use Rails.root.join clause. This is to avoid bugs on operating system that don't use '/' as the path separator.

Comment: This is actually either out of date or was mistaken in the first place. As the rubocop-rails maintainer has explained, "Rails.root is a Pathname instance. Pathname resolves differences in OS path expressions." (https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails/pull/128#issuecomment-530671304).

Comment: Seems you're right, the manual now reads: This cop is used to identify usages of file path joining process to use Rails.root.join clause. It is used to add uniformity when joining paths.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just a "let's pick a style" approach. I don't see any meaningful discussion when the idea was [proposed](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/3779).

Answer (score 1):

It's a default settings. You can read more about options [here](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railsfilepath)

You can change it using *.rubocop.yml* file. Here is an example, take a look at the end of file.

```
inherit_from: .rubocop_todo.yml

AllCops:
  DisplayCopNames: true

  Exclude:
    - bin/**/*
    - db/schema.rb
    - node_modules/**/*

  TargetRubyVersion: 2.3

Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 120

Metrics/MethodLength:
  Exclude:
    - test/**/*

Rails:
  Enabled: true

Rails/FilePath:
  Enabled: false
```

Comment: I am looking for a reason WHY rubocop chose this as the default.

Comment: Maybe some people (creators of Rubocop for example) prefer this style, maybe default option is easier for using of variables in path because it can help to avoid string interpolation.